# What would prevent ASP.NET from Output Caching?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, outputcache

I have an ASP.NET application, and am trying to output cache a certain page, however on every request, the debugger is still hitting the OnLoad method and I get a 200 response back.

I have placed the output cache directive on a page like so:

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="60" VaryByParam="None" %>
```

And ensured I have the OutputCache module

```
<add name="OutputCache" type="System.Web.Caching.OutputCacheModule"/>
```

And have also bypassed URL rewriting just in case. I have tried this using Cassini and IIS 5.1 (XP), however the page is not caching at all.

Are there any other factors which I have not looked at which could affect this feature?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem. I found this line of code being called while handling the request that I couldn't cache:

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
```

Commenting this out made Output caching start working again. I would have guessed that the line above would only affect Headers sent to the client/browser. Make sure nothing like this is being executed at any point in the page life-cycle.